# orderBy not working in laravel + datatable

Tags: laravel, datatable, controller, sql-order-by

I simply want to get the latest date/time per customer id but the orderBy code seems to not be working. I've tried using first but I keep on getting datatable error 7.

controller

```
public function refresh(){
    $cash_advance = DB::table('cash_advance')
        ->join('customer', 'customer.id', '=', 'cash_advance.customer_id')
        ->select('cash_advance.customer_id', 'customer.fname', 'customer.mname', 'customer.lname', 'cash_advance.amount', 'cash_advance.created_at', 'cash_advance.balance')
        ->groupBy('cash_advance.customer_id')
        ->orderBy('cash_advance.created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
    return \DataTables::of($cash_advance)
    ->addColumn('action', function($cash_advance){
        return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" id="'.$cash_advance->customer_id.'"><i class="material-icons" style="width: 25px;">visibility</i></button>';//info/visibility
    })
    ->make(true);
}
```

datatable

```
var cash_advancetable = $('#cash_advancetable').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
            ],
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('refresh_cashadvance') }}",
            columns: [
                {render: function(data, type, full, meta){
                    return full.fname +" "+full.mname+" "+full.lname;
                }},
                {data: 'amount', name: 'amount'},
                {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
                {data: 'balance', name: 'balance'},
                {data: "action", orderable:false,searchable:false}
            ]
        });
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diD5y.png)
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze9zQ.png)

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: there is no error, only that when I use group by it takes the earliest data inserted instead of the latest, the order by descending is not working the way I thought it would.

Comment: try to use `groupBy()` after `orderBy()`

Comment: I tried that as well but it didn't work.

Comment: i can help if i know what error message that mysql is throwing (other than 7)

Comment: the error only occurs when I use the first() method. the code i have given above does not have error however it does not show what I need.

Comment: I've tried putting that code again in order to show it to you it's this DataTables warning: table id=cash_advancetable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: maybe cuz it's executed by ajax, the error not showing, if you have postman try to call that route with it, it shows more info if there is error

Comment: You can see the error in the developer tools "network" tab. Click on the ajax request and go to "preview". Anyway, try setting the config in `config/database.php` strict mode to false: `strict => false`.

Comment: what the purpose of cash advance in '->orderBy('cash_advance.created_at', 'desc')' ? is that your table name ? try to delete cash_advance. because you have the table name in 'DB::table('cash_advance')'

Answer (score 0):

for getting the latest date just use [max aggregator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#Aggregates): `max('cash_advance.created_at')`.

but anyway in the above groupBy statement, you should select all costumers related feature
like this:

```
    DB::table('cash_advance')
    ->join('customer', 'customer.id', '=', 'cash_advance.customer_id')
    ->select('cash_advance.customer_id', 'customer.fname', 'customer.mname', 'customer.lname', 'cash_advance.amount', 'cash_advance.balance', DB::raw('MAX( cash_advance.created_at)'))
    ->groupBy('cash_advance.customer_id', 'customer.fname', 'customer.mname', 'customer.lname', 'cash_advance.amount', 'cash_advance.balance',)
    ->orderBy('cash_advance.customer_id', 'customer.fname', 'customer.mname', 'customer.lname', 'cash_advance.amount', 'cash_advance.balance', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I still get the same result.

Comment: why you didn't use max laravel aggregator??
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#Aggregates

Comment: how can I use it? because I've tried it before and it didn't work

Comment: I get this error after trying the updated code. DataTables warning: table id=cash_advancetable - Requested unknown parameter 'created_at' for row 0, column 2. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: I tried using latest() which worked in one part of my system but it didn't work in this one.

Answer (score 0):

for id shorting please add this $("#dataTable").DataTable({order:[[0,"desc"]]});